# MVC3 passing dictionary values to dropdownlist and binding associated key to the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create a mvc3 c# webapplication. What i'm trying to do, is to create a DropDownlist and passing a dictionary to it. The user in the webinterface should see the values of the dictionary and that works. But i dont want to bind the selected value to the model, instead i want the associated key. Is that somehow possible?

In the example, you see how i bind the selected value to the model:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EditDate, new SelectList(Versions.Values), Model.EditDate)
```

The Versions.Values are DateTimes (values of the dictionary). On Submit the selected Value is bind to model.EditDate. But i want to bind the associated key of the selected Value (values are id).

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the `Dictionary<T1,T2>` to a `SelectList`, usually done using one of the `Linq` extensions. So, if you had:

```
Dictionary<Int32,DateTime> Versions = new Dictionary<Int32,DateTime> {
  { 1, new DateTime(2012, 12, 1) },
  { 2, new DateTime(2013, 1, 1) },
  { 3, new DateTime(2013, 2, 1) },
};
```

Then you could use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EditDate,
  Versions.Select(x => new SelectListItem {
    Text = x.Value.ToShortDateString(),
    Value = x.Key.ToString(),
    Selected = x.Value == Model.EditDate
  })
)
```

(that's assuming `model.EditDate` is an `int` since you're now making the `Keys` of the dictionary the `Value` of the drop-down list.)

Comment: Thank you, thats a good input. But i still get an error, because the EditDate type is an integer while the Value type is a string. Is there any mistake?

Comment: Well, I'm still foggy on what is what. Can you maybe show the datatype of `model.EditDate` and a sample assignment of `Values`?

Comment: It is Working! i just had to change x.Value==Model.EditDate to x.Key==Model.EditDate. Thank you so much!

Comment: So you have the inverse: `Dictionary<DateTime, Int32>`?

Comment: No it is Dictionary<int, DateTime>.

Comment: Then what is `EditDate`, `int`?

Comment: It's actually EditDate_ID but it is int yes